# How to pass scope variable data from one state to another using Angular ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states as follows:

```
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('my.list', {
          url: '/myitem',
          templateUrl: 'templates/my-item-list.html',
          controller: 'myController'
        })

        .state('my.detail', {
          url: '/detail',
          templateUrl: 'templates/item-detail.html',
          controller: 'myController'
        })
```

In `my-item-list.html` I have used ng-repeat to list items, which are clickable.

On click the state changes to `my.detail` where I want to display details of selected/clicked item.

How to pass clicked data from one state to another? What would be best approach to follow? without displaying params in URL?

Answer (score 1):

Best approach while navigating from one state to another on click of a link is by using [**`ui-sref`**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) and you can pass `params` with it like:

```
<a ... ui-sref="my.detail({selected: 'something'})" ...>...</a>
```

In order to make that work, you need `selected` to be part of `params` in that state. Like this:

```
    .state('my.detail', {
      url: '/detail',
      params: {selected: null},
      templateUrl: 'templates/item-detail.html',
      controller: 'myController'
    })
```

Now, you can use that in your `myController` using `$stateParams.selected`.

Comment: will it be same using $state.go('my.detail');

Comment: `ui-sref` can be used in HTML like `<a ... ui-sref="my.detail({...})"..>..</a>`.. if you have direct navigation, you should use `ui-sref`, if you have any logic written in controller and then based on that you are changing states, then you should use `$state.go('my.detail', {...})` in controller

Comment: @SystemMGR you can find more on `ui-sref` [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref). It's very simple to use.

Comment: This solution looks easy but I am using JSON data to render in list (ng-repeat), how can I pass this data to details state?

Comment: @Thanos ask your question seperately mentioning the issues you have and I could help you out

Comment: Ok here you go! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044201/passing-ng-repeat-data-to-another-state-in-angular-ui-router