# Passing ng-repeat data to another state in angular ui router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am facing some problem with ui-router in angularjs. I am trying to pass data from one state to another.

Data:

```
$scope.MyData = [

{
  "name": "Alice",
  "age": "20",
  "email": "example@example.com"
},

{
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": "20",
  "email": "example1@example.com"
}
];
```

View:

```
  <div ng-repeat="data in MyData" >
        <div>
          <span>Name: {{data.name}}</span>
          <span>Age: {{data.age}}</span>
        </div>
   </div>
```

When user clicks on this div, I want to display email data for clicked contact in contact.details state view.

Controller:

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('contact.list', {
          url: '/contacts',
          templateUrl: 'templates/contact-list.html',
          controller: 'contactCtrl'
        })

        .state('contact.details', {
          url: '/contactdetails',
          templateUrl: 'templates/contact-details.html',
          controller: 'contactCtrl'
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `contact.details` state should have `params` .Like this:

```
.state('contact.details', {
    url: '/contactdetails',
    params: {contact: null},
    templateUrl: 'templates/contact-details.html',
    controller: 'contactCtrl'
})
```

put the following attribute from where you want to open the above state:

```
<a ... ui-sref="contact.details({contact: data})" ...>...</a>
```

And, you should be able to navigate to that state with given information. You can access `contact` in `contact.details`'s controller by injecting `$stateParams` and then with `$stateParams.contact`

Comment: How to reset params value? The problem I am facing is when I click the contact-1 1st time it shows correctly, if I go back and select 2nd contact it shows me details of 1st contact.

Comment: @Thanos not sure what's the issue, try to solve it, share more of your code if it persists..